# What Halachot apply to serving on jury duty?

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, chutz-laaretz

Halachically, what are the responsibilities of one who is called to jury duty? What if one of the litigants is Jewish, and the halacha would find differently than civil law does in the case, are you considered to have financially damaged him?

Comment: dinei malchut dinei?

Comment: I know someone who was called for jury duty on a murder case, and he said that he would rule based on what Torah says, not based on his personal feelings, so they dismissed him from the case.

Comment: http://dinonline.org/2011/11/21/jury-service-in-halachah/

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60536/is-trying-to-get-out-of-jury-duty-permitted-halachically

Answer (score 7):

R. Moshe (in [Hoshen Mishpat 1:92](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&st=&pgnum=158)) considers the case where one wants to work as a tax enforcement officer where he might have to turn over Jews to the government to be punished "more than they would be according to the rules of Torah". R. Moshe answer he can take the job, but his first proof is from a case in the gemara where the Jew is forced to inform on another Jew. He then extends that to include also the case of the tax officer who voluntarily applies for the job, and allows it even then. I would liken the juror to the first case and say that based on his logic, jury service is certainly allowed even if the verdict is not according to the Torah law.

Comment: I disagree that the case he addresses can be compared to jury duty.

Comment: Firstly he says that the only reason it's allowed is because if you don't take the job, someone else will check the tax paperwork and surely find the problem. But with jury duty the decision is one that many people might judge differently, so it's not guaranteed to end the same if you don't judge! הנכון לע"ד כיון דבעצם הרי כל מי שיהיה רואה חשבונות ימצא את הפשיעה, וברור שאף אם זה לא ירצה לקבל משרה זו מהממשלה יהיה שם רואה חשבונות, ונמצא שלא יפסיד הפושע יותר כשהוא יקבל המשרה מכשלא יקבל הוא ואחר יהיה שם ולא הזיקו כלום ובלא היזק לא שייך איסור

Comment: Secondly, at the end R Moshe says in the case where one chooses to do the job, it is only allowed because he is not specifically looking for negligence, the vast majority of cases he is just checking and finding correct paperwork. In a jury it seems much closer to a case where you are looking for negligence.

Comment: אבל נראה כיון דהמשרה של רואה חשבונות אינה משרה מיוחדת למצא את הפשיעות שהרי לא ידוע שפשעו כלל ורוב עבודתו הוא לבדוק החשבונות של פנקסיהם בעלמא שיהיו נכונים, ורק לפעמים אפשר יזדמן לידו למצא איזה פשיעה וגם זה לא ידע בתחלת עיונו בהפנקסים שהביא הנתבע מהם שהרי אמר הנתבע שהחשבונות נכונים שבודאי יש לתלות שנדמה לו כן דלא היה כופר כשאפשר לברר, ולכן גם הרואה חשבונות יש לו לתלות שקרוב יותר שימצא שהן נכונים ורק שאפשר שיתגלה פשיעה,...

Comment: אבל נראה כיון דהמשרה של רואה חשבונות אינה משרה מיוחדת למצא את הפשיעות שהרי לא.... ידוע שפשעו כלל ורוב עבודתו הוא לבדוק החשבונות של פנקסיהם בעלמא שיהיו נכונים, ורק לפעמים אפשר יזדמן לידו למצא איזה פשיעה וגם זה לא ידע בתחלת עיונו בהפנקסים שהביא הנתבע מהם שהרי אמר הנתבע שהחשבונות נכונים שבודאי יש לתלות שנדמה לו כן דלא היה כופר כשאפשר לברר, ולכן גם הרואה חשבונות יש לו לתלות שקרוב יותר שימצא שהן נכונים ורק שאפשר שיתגלה פשיעה,

Comment: " I would liken the juror to the first case" - is this your own "psak"?