# Can and should I report cheaters?

Tags: halacha, mussar-ethics, yeshiva-school, college-university-school

Sometimes during an exam, the Rabbi  or professor leaves the room. This provides an opportunity (which some students take) to openly and publicly cheat. (These students are not wearing kipot nor are Jewish.)

Is there any halachic prohibition or recommendation to report this behavior?

Students aren't officially ranked against one another, and the professor probably won't curve the exam.

What should the halachic onlooker do?

Comment: It's not always the case that the cheaters are non-Jews

Comment: 1 - there may be different halachic rulea related to Jews vs. non-Jews. 2 - Assuming the cheaters are Jews, unless they are posing an inherent danger (physical, financial, etc.) by their cheating, I think your reporting them might be *lashon hara*. You are reporting a bad thing about them that serves no purpose to anyone else by your reporting. You can reprove them, directly and appropriately, though.

Comment: In this case, they aren't Jewish.

Comment: Since when does lashon hara only apply to Jews?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56693/loshon-hara-vs-honor-code